# jQuery: Animate to vertical position

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a vertical menu (html list) with an arrow image (as a div). I would like the arrow to slide vertically to the clicked position.

Should be a pretty simple animate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click here to see this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/WAZJf/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Click</li>
  <li>Here</li>
  <li>And</li>
  <li>Watch</li>
  <li>The</li>
  <li>Magic</li>
  <li>Happen</li>
</ul>
<div id="bullet">&diams;</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
ul { list-style:outside circle; padding-left:20px; }
li { cursor: pointer; }
#bullet { color:#0c0; padding:1px 0 0 3px; position:absolute; top:200px; }
​
```

Important part is `#bullet { position:absolute; }`

**jQuery** (in `$(document).ready`)

```
$('li').bind('click', function(e) {
    var offset = $(e.target).offset();
    $('#bullet').animate({'top':offset.top},600);
});​
```

Pretty simple!

Answer (score 0):

Like following perhaps:

```
$('#arrow_image').animate($('#vertical_menu').position(), 'slow');
```

`position` might be `offset` depending on context.

**Edit:** erm, read question wrong :)

to move it to mouse position in a click handler:

```
var click_handler = function(event) {
  $('#arrow_image').animate(
    {
      left: event.pageX - $('#vertical_menu').offset().left 
    }, 'slow');
}
```

`left` depends as usual on context where the arrow image is located in DOM, if it's absolute positioned in relation to `body` then `pageX` is sufficient.